# PhoneGap File Upload Using jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, cordova, file-upload

I develop mobile app using PhoneGap and wanna ask if there is a way to upload a file to server (php) using jQuery's ajax.
I use ajax because I want to avoid redirection from a web page (Of course, I want to redirect to my own page).
So, here is some of my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: $("#myform").serialize(),
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

and I've tried these combinations below but nothing works. Any idea ?

```
contentType: false
cache: false
processData: false
contentType: "multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: Using FormData as you wrote in the comment to Matt's Answer did it for me.
    `var data = new FormData( formElement ), oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST", '/fileUpload', true);
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
        var response;
        if (oReq.status == 200) {
            /* success */
        } else {
            /* failure */
        }
    };
    oReq.send(data);`
Thanx you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to use PhoneGap's FileTransfer class.

Documentation and some example code is here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Comment: I agree, you will have to use the FileTransfer API of PhoneGap.

Comment: I guess I'll try to give my question clearly next time. I already know about FileTransfer, but what I want is upload on the web browser for testing before deploy the app. But I've solved it. What I need is : var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("Id")); and $.ajax({data: fd});

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    alert(formData)
    $.ajax({
        url: '/testupload2/',  //server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        //Ajax events

        success: function(data){
            alert('Done')
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("Some Error!")
        },
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});

function progressHandlingFunction(e){
    if(e.lengthComputable){
        $('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML body part:

```
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="file" type="file" />
<input type="button" id ="button" value="Upload" />
</form>
<progress>
    progressHandlingFunction()
</progress>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload a file using an AJAX call easily.

You could base-encode it or transport it in a different manner, but there are quite a few [file upload plugins for jQuery](https://www.google.com/search?&q=jquery+file+upload+plugin) out there that may help you out.